# What is an efficient way to track the number of times a function has been called within the last minute?

Tags: c++, usage-statistics

I am looking for a way to track the number of times that a function has been called within the last minute.

Every second, I would like to know how many times a function has been called within the last 60 seconds. What is an efficient way to do this?

I thought about using several threads and a vector of timestamps.  Every time the function is called in the first thread, a timestamp item is added to the vector. Another thread watches the end of the vector and removes the last item whenever it is older than 60 seconds.  A third thread would then check the size of the vector every second.

However, this seems like it may be inefficient. What is a better way to track this value?

Comment: I don't see why third thread is necessary. When second thread removes all entries which are older than current time - 60 s, why it cannot report the size when done with this? Actually, when watched function adds a new entry it could clean-up old entries directly afterwards, and report the size of vector when it's done. So, this could work even without any extra threads. (I see a potential problem source in any extra thread. So, I try to prevent multi-threading whenever there are no urgent reasons for this. May be, I'm a bit paranoid...) ;-)

Comment: do you care about the number of calls to this function within the last 1000ms; whatever the time might be, or do you care about the number of calls to this function in each 1000ms chunk?  The latter being much, much easier to do, and just as good for most purposes.

Comment: @UKMonkey I am more concerned with a rolling total for the last 1000ms. Yes, the 1000ms chunks would be easier, but I need to be able to react quickly (within ~10ms range) if the rolling total gets to high.

Comment: @Scheff You are right, I can cut down the number of threads.  The function that I'm tracking in the first thread is called pretty frequently, so I was thinking about trying to minimize the amount of work in it. After thinking about it, doing everything in the main thread shouldn't add too much overhead.

Comment: What granularity do you need (is +/-10ms okay)? And do you expect to be calling this function a lot (say more than 1000 times/second)?

Comment: @BenJones +/- 10ms is fine, and the function may be called between 50-2000 times/second

Comment: Perhaps you could hold a histogram of the calls holding number of calls in millisecond divisions of the second.  Then tracking the value would just involve summing the histogram.  The complicated part would be clearing out the bins, but that could be implemented by "remembering"  the timepoint of the previous function call, and updating whenever you "touch" the histogram.

Comment: This would be fun to do with Redis, then you could query independently of the running program and set keys with 60s timeouts.